# css h1 font-size as big as width

Tags: html, css, header, width, fill

Is it possible to tell a h1 to size the text so it fills the full 100% width of the element?

Like this.

[image]

code:

```
<h1>FOO</h1>
<h1>BAAR</h1>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without JavaScript

Comment: try using `font-size` property within `h1` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this plugin.

http://fittextjs.com/

It's great for responsive text.

**EDIT:**

```
jQuery("#element1").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '540px' });
jQuery("#element2").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '40px', maxFontSize: '340px' });
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the plugin tends to handle one size and then apply it to all elements?

I found another plugin called bigtext that worked pretty good.

https://github.com/zachleat/BigText

Comment: how are you applying the plugin? can you paste an example or jsfiddle?

Comment: you can just apply it to one element? `jQuery("#test").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '340px' });`

Comment: Yeah, well I have two elements?

Comment: Ok, then I need to calculate how big the font should be in relative to each other right?

Comment: Yeah and you can declare that with `minFontSize` and `maxFontSize`

Comment: Ok, thanks but I think I'll stick with BigText, take a look at it, it does that but automatically. =)

Comment: As 7 people have voted up this I'm checking this as the correct answer even though I ended up with BigText.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin called bigtext that works pretty well, will wait for comments though.

https://github.com/zachleat/BigText

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution with jQuery would be:

```
var cs=$("#content").width();
$("h1").each(function(){
var hs=$(this).width();
while(hs<cs)
{
    $("h1").css("font-size",hs+0.01+"px");
    var hs=$(this).width();
}
while(hs>cs)
{
    $("h1").css("font-size",hs-0.01+"px");
    var hs=$(this).width();
}

})
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't work, to extract width with .css can't be right? I mean you get eg. 300px out of that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I made an edit. The thing is that i didn't test it but the main ideea is presented and it should theoretic work.